# Application fails to read from intermediate topic after restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using Kafka Streams in our application. The topology uses `groupByKey`, followed by windowing followed by aggregation.

Sometimes, after restart, the application fails to read from the intermediate `.repartition` topic, e.g, lag is growing bigger and bigger. Deleting the `.repartition` topic solves the problem till the next restart, but it is not a good solution. The application runs on docker with local storage mounted as state directory.

Seems like without docker, everything is OK. Please, advise!
Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

Someone experiencing a similar issue was able to resolve it by setting `metadata.max.age.ms` to a lower value than the current default (300000) -- try setting it quite low (eg few hundred ms) to see if that helps, then work out a reasonable value to run with.